# Long live for a selenium script?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Let's say I have a webpage that I need to have some selenium script to automate the UI testing. This page has a list of sections, in the order of "Section A", "Section B", "Section C", etc. Here is my piece of code to automate the steps on "Section B" area testing.

```
  by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
  dropdown_in_SectionB = "#app > div.app > div > div > div.content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(7) > ..."
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, target))).click()
```

Unfortunately, I can not find a XPATH value for this "drowdown_in_SectionB" area, and I have to use css_selector value here. And it works ok for this second.

But later on, this page has been updated, the updated page now contains "Section A", "SectionX", "Section B", "Section C", in such order. And my above script is broken, as the css_selector value of drowpdown_in_Section becomes:

```
  dropdown_in_SectionB = #app > div.app > div > div > div.content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(8) > ..."
```

So I have to update the script to have it back to working, which is annoyed.

My question is how may I find a way that the script is smart enough to locate the location in its "css_selector" value, however the change is ?

If it was of XPATH value, I can easily have it solved, as I have other clues to trace the dropdown area in Section, but how this can be done in case of css_selector value ???

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: XPATH and CSS have pretty much the same functionality... it's just a different syntax.

Comment: If it was for XPAH, I could have as if: dropdown_in_SectionB = "//div[contains(text(), 'Section B')]/../following-sibling::div[1]/...", to locate that field, which is based on whatever "Section B" location is, to sub-trace the field in its section area.  But using  css_selector value, I don't have such option here ?

Comment: just read up on CSS selectors...  (I never use them myself, but you can do the same with CSS).  Why does it matter which you use?  (xpath or css selector?)

Comment: Just like the xpath example I have give above,  it is to locate the div where its text() is "Section B" first, then to find this section's siblings based on that.  So even if  this section has moved, we always can locate "Section B" by this name in xpath way.  But css_selector way is as if:  "from the very beginning > find its neighbor > find neighbor's neighbor >...> reach my target".  If the location has changed, we need to rewire everything.

Comment: @pcalkins : No they are pretty much different. Not just syntax-wise. xpath native support is not available on most browsers thus selenium needs third-party vendors to have support for XPath. You will see the difference the moment you switch your browser to Safari/Edge/Phantom JS etc.

Comment: @user3595231 : Update the question with relevant HTML code. We can form both CSS and XPath.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that the webelement has it's own find methods that will operate in that scope.  (So you can find all the child nodes regardless of locator syntax used...)